# GhostScript - text misplaced after converting from pdf to jpg

Tags: php, pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I am using PHP `exec()` and GhostScript to convert my PDF files to JPG, however, there seems to be an issue with text - the letters gets misplaced. Here are example screenshots how it turns out:

This is how it is on PDF - http://screencast.com/t/vmF2kJdlts
And this is how it turns out on JPG - http://screencast.com/t/BTFNMkrc

Here's the command I'm using:
`exec("/usr/bin/gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=test.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r814x1149 -q test.pdf", $out, $rcode);`

The PDF itself is generated with dompdf and custom installed font if that helps.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you supply the PDF for inspection?

Comment: Here's a link https://www.dropbox.com/s/wa0760utyc2fwyy/test.pdf

Comment: I also can not convert this document to image using adobe acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

After converting it with GS9.07win the text looks fine (text is rendered  with default font, Arial). Most probably the problem with OpenSans and OpenSans-Bold fonts substitution or incomplete glif maps.

Comment: So basically it means that GhostScript has it's own font library where I need to install OpenSans?

Comment: [GS link](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution) *-sFONTDIR=c:/windows/fonts -sCIDFMAP=lib/cidfmap*

Comment: I have tried to convert your PDF file with help of my component, image looks like the original pdf. The only thing that could be incorrect in your case are the /W width calculations.(I mean */W [0 [883] 32 [260] 33 [267] 34 [401] 35 [646] 36 [572] 37 [823] 38* ...)